# What are the semantics of assignment in an interface?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-emf, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore

I came across the following code. It is an interface in which there is an assignment of attributes. I understood interfaces could only be used to declare methods. What is the purpose of this?

```
interface Literals {
    /**
     * The meta object literal for the '{@link bowling.impl.PlayerImpl <em>Player</em>}' class.
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!-- end-user-doc -->
     * @see bowling.impl.PlayerImpl
     * @see bowling.impl.BowlingPackageImpl#getPlayer()
     * @generated
     */
    EClass PLAYER = eINSTANCE.getPlayer();

    /**
     * The meta object literal for the '<em><b>Name</b></em>' attribute feature.
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!-- end-user-doc -->
     * @generated
     */
    EAttribute PLAYER__NAME = eINSTANCE.getPlayer_Name();

    /**
     * The meta object literal for the '<em><b>Date Of Birth</b></em>' attribute feature.
     * <!-- begin-user-doc -->
     * <!-- end-user-doc -->
     * @generated
     */
    EAttribute PLAYER__DATE_OF_BIRTH = eINSTANCE.getPlayer_DateOfBirth();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **Constants**.

Quoting [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3), section 9 "Interfaces", subsection 9.3 "Field (Constant) Declarations":

> Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly `public`, `static`, and `final`. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.

Specifying the implicit modifiers would be the same, but perhaps clarifying it:

```
interface Literals {
    public static final EClass PLAYER = eINSTANCE.getPlayer();
    public static final EAttribute PLAYER__NAME = eINSTANCE.getPlayer_Name();
    public static final EAttribute PLAYER__DATE_OF_BIRTH = eINSTANCE.getPlayer_DateOfBirth();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but this does not tell why it has to be an interface. It could still be class Literals in your example. They could have written public static final aswell^^

Comment: @Friwi True, but it wasn't a question of "why it has to be", it's a question of "what are the semantics", to which the answer is: They are constants.

Answer (score 2):

I would call it anti-pattern. Interfaces are meant for defining contracts using methods. In the provided interfaces, it seems to be used for global variables purpose.

Logically, it does not make sense for an interface to have properties/attributes, classes should be used for an entity with attributes and operations. This could be done using a class and static imports for the same purpose.

Comment: Java does not support multiple inheritances, but allows a class to conform to multiple interfaces. Does this look like a workaround?